# Question about a proof of boundedness of a continuous function on a closed interval.

Tags: real-analysis

My book gives proof as follows:

> *Thm*
>
> Let $I:= [a,b]$ be a closed bounded interval and lef $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $I$. Then $f$ is bounded on $I$.
>
> *Proof*
>
> Suppose that $f$ is not bdd on $I$. Then, for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$
>   there is a number $x_n \in I$ such that $|f(x_n)| >n$.

I agree.

> Since $I$ is bdd, the sequence $X = (x_n)$ is bdd. Therefore the
>   Bolzano-Weierstrass Thm implies that there is a subsequence $X' =
> > (x_{n_r})$ of $X$ that converges to a number $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Agreed.

> Since $I$ is closed and the elements of $X'$ belong to $I$, it
>   follows that $x\in I$. Then $f$ is continuous at $x$, so that $(f(x_{n_r}))$ converges to $f(x)$. And all convergent sequences are bdd.

Agreed. Note that this text uses " (  ) " for sequences rather than " { } ".

> But this is a contradiction since   $$|f(x_{n_r})|>n_r>r$$   Therefore
>   the supposition that the continuous function $f$ is not bounded on the
>   closed bounded interval $I$ leads to a contradiction. Q.E.D.

I just don't see the contradiction. My argument is that just because there exists a convergent sequence in $I$ making a specific sequence $(f(x_{n_r}))$ converge to a bdd $f(x)$ that doesn't mean that there doesn't exists some value on I where f(x) is unbdd. I think this proof would be fine if there was an added statement like "and every $x \in I$ is a cluster point of $I$" implying that we can generate a convergent sequence to each point. But i feel like there's something more I'm missing here or misinterpreting.

Comment: If you have agreed to those three parts, its bit hard to believe that you don't see the contradiction. The sequence $f(x_{n_r}) $ converges so it is bounded and since $|f(x_{n_r}) |>r$ it is unbounded.

Comment: This proof shows that there exists *a* convergent subsequence on $I$, i.e. $(x_{n_r}) \to x$. This results in a bdd f(x). But the supposition is "suppose that $f$ is not bdd on $I$. I don't see how showing that $f$ is bdd at a single point is a contradiction to supposing $f$ might not be bounded considering the entire interval.

Comment: You may perhaps try to use a direct proof if you are not comfortable with contradiction. By continuity $f$ is bounded in some neighborhood of each point of $I$. Together these neighborhoods form an open cover for $I$ and by Heine Borel, a finite subcover exists and $f$ is bounded on each of these neighborhoods (included in finite cover), so $f$ is bounded on $I$.

Comment: No that's not the point of the proof. The point is that $f(x_{n_r}) $ converges and hence bounded. But the way sequence $x_n$ is constructed the sequence $f(x_{n_r}) $ is unbounded.

Comment: This comment, for some reason, is what triggered my understanding. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to know you finally got it! Enjoy studying related theorems for [continuous functions on closed intervals](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/06/continuous-functions-on-closed-interval-boundedness-property.html).

Answer (score 5):

Since $x_{n_{r}}\rightarrow x$, then by the sequential characterisation of continuity of $f$, then $f(x_{n_{r}})\rightarrow f(x)$, so $|f(x_{n_{r}})|\rightarrow|f(x)|$. But the inequality $|f(x_{n_{r}})|>r$ forces that $|f(x_{n_{r}})|\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Is $|f(x_{n_r})|$ a sequence or a function value? Because my text's proof simply supposes there is *a* number $x_n$ s.t. $|f(x_n)| > r$. You're supposing that there's a sequence where all the terms are unbounded.

Comment: $|f(x_{n_{r}})|$ is a real number, and $(|f(x_{n_{r}})|)_{r}$ is a sequence.

Comment: It doesn't look (to me) like your proof accounts for every number $x_n$ that could exist on $I$. It looks like it only accounts for special cases where $x_n$ is part of a convergent sequence.

Comment: $|f(x_{n_{r}})|$ is a real number by the function value of $f$ at $x_{n_{r}}$, and then by absolute value.

Comment: All $x_{n}$ are in $I$, of course then $x_{n_{r}}$ are in $I$.

Comment: "But the inequality $|f(x_{n_{r}})|>r$ forces that $|f(x_{n_{r}})|\rightarrow\infty$." I don't see why this statement is valid. All we need is one such $x_{n_r}$ where $|f(x_{n})|>n$ for any $n$, for the supposition to hold, meaning that I don't take your conclusion as contradictory to the supposition that there exists some number $x_n$ that causes unboundedness.

Comment: It appears as that all you've shown is that there exists a subsequence in $I$ that causes convergence.

Comment: I there an implied fact here that every single point $x$ of an Interval $I$ in $\mathbb{R}$ can be shown to have a convergent sequence $x_n$on that interval that converges to $x$. And if so, which proof is that?